# XCode Error on creating archive for Generic Device

Tags: objective-c

> **error:** make directory
>   /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Application-gijbetvhfmflwadwicdemgmykala/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Weflymate/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Application.app/Application.app/Application.app/.........
>   : **File name too long**

On Xcode i try to archive a project to create the .ipa.
The IDE blocks the process launching the error that seems a recursive path creation.

Xcode 7.3.1,
MAC OS Sierra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your application file name is too long. Apple allows only 15 characters for your application.

So make application name short or use small characters which takes less space like **"iiiii is taking less space than mmmmm"**

So please make your app name smaller than 15 characters

Answer (score 0):

Try below listed points, that may solve problem:

1) Check if your project contains duplicate framework, if any remove it. Check frameworks in *"Embedded Binaries"* for duplicate and if you find any remove it.

2) Remove duplicate bundle from project which added from other source. Check for duplicate copy of `en.lproj` and remove it.

3) Delete `/Users/..../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and rebuild, because `error: make directory ....Directory not empty` may be for the same.

4) Rename your project with shorter name and then clean and rebuild.